# Auto-populating field using spatial location of another feature and its attributes using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, select-by-attribute, attribute-assistant

I am using ArcMap.

I want to auto-populate a field based on the spatial location of another feature's attribute.

Add a point on top of a building.
The point automatically adds the name of the building.

Can this be done using some sort of an event trigger?

The goal is to assist field workers using what seems like simple GIS logic.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using building polygons with points that lie somewhere within the polygon use a spatial join to join each building with the point residing in it.  Then calculate your field in the point feature class based on the joined building polygon feature class field of choice.

Answer (score 4):

The Attribute Assistant allows you to take field values from intersecting or nearby features and put them in specified fields of the created feature.  It can be configured to populate fields when a feature is created, or on a selected set of features, and when you update a feature's attributes or position.

There is a tutorial [here](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=e35580f27bce4782b95ea8296ac60927), and a blog post on how I implemented it [here](http://summitcountygis.blogspot.com/2012/04/my-journey-to-success-with-attribute.html).

It is a powerful tool that has saved me a great deal of typing and data entry error.  I have it configured to create sequential ids, grab ids of nearby features, get house numbers from the intersecting parcels.

It can do a great deal more.

Answer (score -1):

I would have thought a simple spatial query based on the point would select the building from the building layer, and from there, a simple update on the point object based on the details from the selection.

It's not a large body of work; search at point, select and update.

Answer (score -1):

If you have your two data layers in a relational database (as opposed to 2 shapefiles or similar), what if you just had a field on the point layer that you could populate with the unique ID of the building feature?  That way you could join/relate any of the information from the building layer back to your point.

If you are manually placing the point on top of the building, it doesn't seem like this would have to be a spatial operation...