# Auto-populating field using spatial location of another feature and its attributes using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, fields-attributes, attribute-rules

I'd like to auto-populate a field based on its spatial location of another feature. For example, I have a US County layer and a polygon feature class called "Locations" illustrated below:

[image]

When I add new polygons A & B to my "Locations" layer, how can I auto-populate the County Name from those unique spatial locations?

There's a similar question at [Auto-populating field using spatial location of another feature and its attributes using ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8710).

However the answers were not in line with the original question or referred to a tool called Attribute Assistant. I was able to upload Attribute Assistant successfully to my ArcGIS Pro, but not sure how to enable the tool.

I tried doing a spatial join with my "Locations" layer with the County layer, but the logic of this auto-populate would need some sort of identification which I'm not sure on.

I'm using ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Have you looked at "Add Attribute Rules" in ArcGIS Pro? https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/add-attribute-rule.htm

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately this requires a Standard or Advanced license.  I only have a Basic license.